# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when using pickle

Tags: python, pickle

When I try and open the pickle file, this error appears:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (coinsv_thread):
Exception in thread Thread-2 (coinsv_thread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gregory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Gregory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gregory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gregory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Gregory\Desktop\Y7 Homework\Actual cOMPUTING ASESSMENT\Assesment-Y7\functionality.py", line 30, in coinsv_thread
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Gregory\Desktop\Y7 Homework\Actual cOMPUTING ASESSMENT\Assesment-Y7\functionality.py", line 30, in coinsv_thread
    with open('rlog.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
    with open('rlog.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Here is the code:

```
def coinsv_thread(g):
    #try:
    if True:
        import pickle
        import webclient
        SERVER_URL = "http://gregglesthegreat.pythonanywhere.com/"
        with open('rlog.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
            a = pickle.load(handle)
            handle.close()
        if a[0] == 1:
            my_dict = webclient.get_variable(SERVER_URL, "d_pgp_LOGIN")
            my_user = my_dict.get(a[1])
            my_coins = my_user[1]
            my_new_coins = int(my_coins) + int(g)
            my_user[1] = my_new_coins
            my_dict[a[1]] = my_user
            webclient.update_variable(SERVER_URL, "d_pgp_LOGIN", my_dict)
        else:
            print("Not logged in.")
    #except Exception as e:
    #    print("Fail: ", e)

def coinsv(g):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=coinsv_thread, args=(g,))
    thread.start()
```

I have tried to open the file in the python shell, which works, and I have asked AI online for help.

Comment: please post traceback error could be anywhere, but not in that open statement

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Could it be that `open` was somehow replaced by another function, e. g. `os.fdopen`? Try `print(open)` just before the line with the error.

Comment: That is not a minimal reproducible example. I agree with Michael that it appears you have redefined `open` to refer to something other than the normal builtin of that name. But without the top-level imports, etc., we have no idea what you've done. When dealing with problems of this nature always simplify the code and test your assumptions. Can you write a trivial program that eliminates `coinsv_thread` and replaces the body of `consv` with just a simple `with open('rlog.pkl', 'rb') as handle: print(handle)` and run that successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because of very bad practice of importing all objects of `os` with `from` which ends up shadowing built-in `open` by `os.open` which expects the second argument as integer:

```
>>> from os import *
>>> open('flllf','ff')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

An alternate quick solution if `from os import *` must remain is to add this after importing:

```
from os import *
del open
```

that deletes the reference of `open` as `os.open` and the built-in `open` is visible again.

That said, this makes the code hard to read. The recommended solution is:

- remove `from os import *`
- prefix all calls to `os` modules by `os.` (the calls will fail if not prefixed, test the script thoroughly)